# Java Firestore - Error: Use FieldPath.of() for field names containing '˜*/[]'

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing Java code to interact with a Firestore database. I need to access a field containing a forward-slash in the field name:

```
f.col1 = document.getString("username");
f.col2 = document.getString("subject");
f.col3 = document.getString("details/comments");
```

When I run the code, I get the following error for the line getting Col3:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Use FieldPath.of() for field names containing '˜*/[]'.
```

I am unable to work out how to correctly use this method and I cannot find any documentation on how I should correctly use it (Googling brings up an equivalent JS method). When I attempt to use the FieldPath.of() method, as follows:

```
f.col3 = document.getString(FieldPath.of("details/comments"));
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
java: incompatible types: com.google.cloud.firestore.FieldPath cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

I have no control over the structure of the Firebase data, so I need to work with this field name.

I am using the following documentation to interact with the database:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#java_9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `FieldPath.of` for that last field:

```
f.col3 = document.getString(FieldPath.of("details/comments"));
```

If the `/` was meant to indicate the `comments` is a subfield inside the `details` map, the correct separator would be a `.` btw:

```
f.col3 = document.getString(FieldPath.of("details.comments"));
```

---

For your second error, it looks like [`DocumentSnapshot.getString()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getString(java.lang.String)) only exists with a `String` parameter, so you'll want to use `get()` which accepts a `FieldPath`:

```
f.col3 = document.get(FieldPath.of("details/comments"));
```

or

```
f.col3 = document.get(FieldPath.of("details.comments"));
```

If you're getting a string conversion error here, add `toString()` to the call.

Comment: Hi Frank. Thank you for your response. I have already tried your first suggestion. I have edited my question to better clarify this. I am getting an incompatible types error when trying to do so. Any advice for this?

Comment: I added some more info on this, but I'm basically just browsing the reference docs for the classes that involved at this point, so I recommend keeping those handy.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that fixes the error I was having :). I added an edit to your question to better reflect my additional situation.